# Rounding to Integer with MPFR

Tags: c++, rounding, fibonacci, gmp, mpfr

I've written a small program meant to count the digits of a Fibonacci number, but I've had to use MPFR and GMP because of how large the numbers get. I am getting the correct values, but I need to be able to round them up to the nearest integer, and the rounding modes included with MPFR round, predictably, to float values. Is there a simple way to perform mpfr_t rounding to an int?

Comment: Take a look at http://chschneider.eu/programming/mpfr_real/ - then finish with a cast to (int)

Comment: Bummer, I thought this would work, but I got an invalid cast error.

Comment: "Thought this would work" - can you show the code you used?

Comment: `mpfr_get_z` then use GMP functions, or directly `mpfr_get_ui` or `mpfr_get_si`?

Comment: @Floris right, sorry. I did `mpfr::real<4096> a = .3; int b = a;` and I get `error: cannot convert 'mpfr::real<40961>' to 'int' in initialization`. I don't know where that extra `1` came from in the error, but I assumed it was a bug, since the site lists it as an 'early alpha'. I get a very similar error when I try the cast in assignment instead of initialization. Also, @Marc, thanks! I wish I had found that on my own. If you make it an answer I'd thumb you up and accept it. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Did you try `mpfr::real<4096> a = 0.3; double d; d = (double) a; int b; b = (int) d;`? Otherwise I think you found what you wanted in Marc's suggestion.

Comment: Marc's answer did work for me, but I do think yours would work too because casting to a double seemed to work fine. I'm at work now, but I love the simplicity of it, and I will give it a shot when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

You can first use `mpfr_get_z` and then GMP functions, or directly `mpfr_get_ui` or `mpfr_get_si`.

Answer (score 0):

MPFR has [integer related functions](http://cs.swan.ac.uk/%7Ecsoliver/ok-sat-library/internet_html/doc/doc/Mpfr/3.0.0/mpfr.html/Integer-Related-Functions.html#Integer-Related-Functions); round, floor, ceil, truncate, and nearest integer to convert integers

```
int mpfr_rint (mpfr t rop, mpfr t op, mp rnd t rnd)
int mpfr_ceil (mpfr t rop, mpfr t op) 
int mpfr_floor (mpfr t rop, mpfr t op)
int mpfr_round (mpfr t rop, mpfr t op)
int mpfr_trunc (mpfr t rop, mpfr t op)
```

> Set rop to op rounded to an integer. mpfr_rint rounds to the nearest representable integer in the given rounding mode, mpfr_ceil rounds to the next higher or equal representable integer, mpfr_floor to the next lower or equal representable integer, mpfr_round to the nearest representable integer, rounding halfway cases away from zero (as in the roundTiesToAway mode of IEEE 754-2008), and mpfr_trunc to the next representable integer toward zero.

Then use the conversions like `mpfr_get_z` to get `mpz_t`.